# Prevent Backspace to avoid erasing of initial value in text box in React

Tags: reactjs, textbox, antd, preventdefault

I am using **antd** in my project.
The code is :

```
<FormItem  style={{'marginLeft':'-28px', 'marginTop':'10px'}}
>
 {getFieldDecorator('invoiceNumber', {
 initialValue: this.state.TxnNumber ? this.state.TxnNumber : "#",
  rules: [{                       
 required: false, message: 'Please Input Invoice!',
 }],
 })(
 <Input placeholder="S.O.NO#" style={{'width':'120px','height':'28px' }} onChange={(e)=>{e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();                                   
 this.handleChange(0,e, 'invoiceNumber')}}  />
 )}                  
</FormItem>
```

---

```
handleChange = (index, e, field) => {
if(field == 'invoiceNumber')
    this.state.TxnNumber = e.target.value;
}
```

I want symbol "#" as the initial value in my text box. Also prevent back space from removing the "#" symbol. 
How to do this in React?

Answer (score 0):

Just use controlled input so you can control the initial value of input in the handler method like this:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: '#'
    }
  }

  handleChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    this.setState({ value: value || '#'  })
  }
  
  render(){
    const { value } = this.state;
    
    return (
      <input
        value={value}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This isn't working with antd. "value' is not defined" error showing in handleChange

Comment: it might be the problem with state initialisation. Either use the "traditional" constructor, or (I think the easier way) install `transform-class-properties` babel plugin (and add it into plugins section in `.babelrc`.) So state = { value: '#' } part will work. This is just the sorthand of `constructor(){super(); this.state = {value: '#'} }` syntax.

Comment: @JaneFred, I completed my answer with constructor. Is it working for you now? Does this behaviour cover your needs? Thx.